# Inserir em duas tabelas obrigatoriamente caso não, rollback

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando que caso dê erro em tentativa de gravar, ou por algum motivo grave em uma e não grave em outra, é realizado o rollback em ambas tabelas, eu encontrei coisas similares, porém não localizei nada que precisasse.

Esta é a criação da minha proc

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_IncluirCadastro`( in nome VARCHAR(45), in sobrenome VARCHAR(100), in email VARCHAR(100), in rg VARCHAR(45), in cpf VARCHAR(45), in pai VARCHAR(45), in mae VARCHAR(45), in celular01 VARCHAR(30), in celular02 VARCHAR(30), in telefone VARCHAR(30), in telefonerecado VARCHAR(30), IN rua VARCHAR(100), IN numero VARCHAR(30), IN bairro VARCHAR(100), IN estado VARCHAR(45), IN cidade VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
   @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
  SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
  SELECT @full_error;
 END;

SET autocommit = 0;
START transaction;
     INSERT INTO `Teste`.`CadastroPF`(Nome, 
                                      Sobrenome, 
                                      Email,
                                      RG,  
                                      CPF, 
                                      Pai,
                                      Mae, 
                                      Celular01, 
                                      Celular02,
                                      Telefone,
                                      TelefoneRecado) 
    VALUES
    (nome, sobrenome, email, rg, cpf, pai, mae, celular01, celular02, telefone, telefonerecado);

    INSERT INTO `Teste`.`Endereco`(Rua, 
                                      Numero, 
                                      Bairro,  
                                      Estado, 
                                      Cidade) 
    VALUES
    (rua, numero, bairro, estado, cidade);


END
```

Como eu gravo:

```
CALL SP_IncluirCadastro('Ezequiel', 'Delavega Martins', 'abc@hotmail.com', '461514344', '38094345830', 'Afonso Ramos', 'Mamãe querida', '11942026774', '11998333777', '1155303117', '1191232111', 'dos aniquis', '2142142144', 'jd. santa terezinha', 'são paulo', 'SP')
```

Comment: Você tem de tratar a "exception" creio , não programo com mysql mas ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905900/mysql-transaction-roll-back-on-any-exception

Comment: Vou tentar algo similar por aqui, nossa é tão ruim no mysql, mas agradeço Motta!!!!!!!

Comment: Achei até simples , em Oracle é até mais complicado.